# Ways to decouple initialization order from storage order

Tags: c++, initialization, memory-layout

Suppose I want to be able to do memory layout optimization for objects of class `Foo`:

```
class Foo
    {
    T1 m_x;
    T2 m_y;
    };
```

Now, T1:s must always have a valid reference to T2:s, thus forcing me to initialize T2 first. But that is not possible, since `m_x` goes first. I could make a default constructor for T1, but then it is possible to have `m_x` in a zombie state. Are there any other options?

In this case, T1 represents a view of T2. That is, it would be possible to change T2 afterwards, but I want T2 to always refer to a valid object:

```
class T1
    {
    public:
        explicit T1(const T2& obj):r_obj(&obj){}
        explicit T1(T2&& obj)=delete; //Don't ever pass a temporary object here...
        void set(const T2& obj) noexcept //Replace the view
            {r_obj=&obj;}

        void set(T2&& obj)=delete; //Again, temporaries are forbidden
        void doStuffThatRequiresObjToBeNonNull();

    private:
        const T2* r_obj;
    };
```

Comment: Why not ask yourself why these classes are so tightly coupled ? Maybe they should be the same class ? Or at least reflect the dependency between `T1` and `T2` using encapsulation.

Comment: If you just take reference of `m_y`, it is *ok*.

Comment: @Jarod42, Assuming the T1 ctor does not use obj.

Comment: That is what I mean by "just take reference".